# Angular2 and testing EventEmitter

Tags: testing, angular, jasmine

I have a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/WuoPHiTEqZvECxmrZ6eX), and been trying to figure out how to test the EventEmitter after having tried following some of the suggestions on the web without success. I would like to know how to test it by triggering a click of the button...so more of a component test. The code is within the **voter.component.ts** and **voter.componet.spec.ts** file. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
it('should emit on up/down vote click', fakeAsync((): void => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(VoterComponent);
    let instance: VoterComponent = fixture.componentInstance;

    spyOn(instance.onVote, 'emit');
    let button = findElement(fixture, 'button:first-child');
    button.click();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    expect(instance.onVote.emit).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
}));
```

Comment: What's not working about this? It looks fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. When I run the test, it's failing with the error "Expected spy emit to have been called"...so I'm not sure whether the button click isn't correct or what. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first observation is that @Input and @Output decorations always need to be followed by a pair of parentheses, more details on the subject [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs).

The second issue in your code was that you were incrementing `counter` instead of `this.counter` inside the onVote() event handler method.

Also, as a side note, the VoterComponent does not need to be declared in the directives array of the parent (App) component.

[Working plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yMP3uQiO9IRbkv2RlHWb?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for that. It is a bad attempt of mine to copy and convert code I had written to plunkr while changing a couple things, so as to just demonstrate what I was trying to do more simply. Thank you none the less, especially the last point. But my main question was around writing a test around it - if you take a look at the test I pasted in my original post, I wasn't having any luck as it was as though the emit function wasn't being called.